# My Flask can not display the mysql row correctly

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to select the rows in which the "NomeAbrev" column is equal to each required value *(in this case: 'vitamina_a', 'vitamina_b', 'adh', and 'ferro')*, and then display the complete row for each value.

I can run MySQL correctly for each of the items, but when displaying in the template, it only shows the line of one of them ('ferro' line, in this case). As you can see the output:

```
vitamina_c: 0.5 (('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 131.0, 137.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 132.0, 138.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 100000000.0, 26.7, 'Mulheres na pr\xc3\xa9-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 2.69, 19.59, 'Mulheres na p\xc3\xb3s-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'))
vitamina_a: 0 (('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 131.0, 137.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 132.0, 138.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 100000000.0, 26.7, 'Mulheres na pr\xc3\xa9-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 2.69, 19.59, 'Mulheres na p\xc3\xb3s-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'))
adh: 7 (('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 131.0, 137.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 132.0, 138.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 100000000.0, 26.7, 'Mulheres na pr\xc3\xa9-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 2.69, 19.59, 'Mulheres na p\xc3\xb3s-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'))
ferro: 3 (('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 131.0, 137.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 132.0, 138.0, 'Mulheres no terceiro trimestre de gravidez', 'Tua sa\xc3\xbade'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 65.0, 175.0, 'Homens', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 50.0, 170.0, 'Mulheres', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 100000000.0, 26.7, 'Mulheres na pr\xc3\xa9-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'), ('ferro', 2.69, 19.59, 'Mulheres na p\xc3\xb3s-menopausa', 'Laborat\xc3\xb3rio Hermes Pardini'))
```

My code is like this:

```
for i in Dados:
    PuxaDados   =   "SELECT nomeAbrev, valoresMin, valoresMax, grupo, fonte FROM valores_ref WHERE nomeAbrev = %s"
    Cursor.execute(PuxaDados, (i[0])) # so far so good
    SelectAll   =   Cursor.fetchall()

return render_template('finalizar.html',
    title='Selecionar exames',
    results=Dados,
    SELECIONA_TUDO = SelectAll)
```

Template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for i in results %}
{{ i[0] }}: {{ i[1] }}
{{ SELECIONA_TUDO }} #  Here is where the array of each should appear.
<br>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It is because when iterating through items you `fetchAll` for each `Dados` and in the end you got only last one. In order to display all, you need to cache `SelectAll` for all values.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi So how can I solve? Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see you iterate over `Dados` and fetch it after each iteration. In order to show them all, you need to cache them.

**Python code**

```
SelectAll = []
for i in Dados:
   PuxaDados   =   "SELECT nomeAbrev, valoresMin, valoresMax, grupo, fonte FROM valores_ref WHERE nomeAbrev = %s"
    Cursor.execute(PuxaDados, (i[0])) # so far so good
    SelectAll.append(Cursor.fetchall())

return render_template('finalizar.html',
    title='Selecionar exames',
    results=Dados,
    SELECIONA_TUDO = SelectAll)
```

I also adjusted template, in case you don't need to draw `SELECIONA_TUDO` in each for loop iteration.

**Template**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for i in results %}
{{ i[0] }}: {{ i[1] }}
<br>
{% endfor %}

{% for x in SELECIONA_TUDO %}
{{ x }}
<br><br>
{% endfor %}
<br>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It save me a lot. But now the array is showing three times the same array.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Actually the output was already displaying three times the same thing, as you can see in the code quoted in the post.

Comment: @MarshallVegas I do know, I propose my fix in the post.

Comment: I edited your code, now it's correct! Thank you very much